# Get row's index (or id) inside ng-repeat to do some actions on a specific row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angular and i want to get specific  row's index to execute the function `hidestuff()` on it, i pass `item.id` to the function and i want to hide the row witch contain this id .. but how can i pass the row index to delete the whole row?

html:

```
                  <tr ng-repeat="item in ItemsByPage[currentPage]">
                        <td>
                          <div  ng-model="tid" 
                                ng-hide="hidden" 
                                ng-class="{fade: startFade}"> 

                               {{item.id}} 
                          </div>                                
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <div editable-text="item.name" 
                                onaftersave='inlineupdateName(item.id,item.name)' 
                                ng-model="tname" data-n='item.name'>

                                {{item.name}}
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <div editable-text="item.phone" 
                                 onaftersave='inlineupdatephone(item.id,item.phone)'
                                 ng-model="tphone">
                                 {{item.phone}}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <input  type="text" ng-model="delId"   class="form-control" 
                         placeholder="Enter user id to delete th user">                        
                <button ng-click="deleteuser(delId)"  type="button" 
                        class="btn btn-primary">

                        Delete User
                </button>
```

js:

```
$scope.hideStuff = function (delId) {
                $scope.startFade = true;
                 //here i want to use the index to delete the row
                $scope.hidden = true;
            };
            $scope.deleteuser = function (dalId) {                   
                var data = {delId : $scope.delId};
                $http.post('delete.php', data )
                  .success(function(response) {
                    $scope.hideStuff(delId);
                  });  

            };
```

Comment: you can get the index using the $index see the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @Overmachine i read it , but how to get the index that fits with `delId` in function in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $index please read this for more info:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

I my opinion you should do like this:

```
            <tr id="tr-{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in ItemsByPage[currentPage]">
                    <td>
                      <div> 
                           {{item.id}} 
                      </div>                                
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <div editable-text="item.name" 
                            onaftersave='inlineupdateName(item.id,item.name)' 
                            ng-model="tname" data-n='item.name'>

                            {{item.name}}
                       </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <div editable-text="item.phone" 
                             onaftersave='inlineupdatephone(item.id,item.phone)'
                             ng-model="tphone">
                             {{item.phone}}
                        </div> 
                    </td>
                </tr>

             <input  type="text" ng-model="delId"   class="form-control" 
                     placeholder="Enter user id to delete th user">                        
            <button ng-click="deleteuser(delId)"  type="button" 
                    class="btn btn-primary">

                    Delete User
            </button>
```

js

```
        $scope.hideStuff = function (delId) { 
            $("#tr-"+delId).hide();
            //the entire tr (line table) will be hidden.
            // you don't need those $scope variables to hide the elements
        };
        $scope.deleteuser = function (dalId) {                   
            var data = {delId : $scope.delId};
            $http.post('delete.php', data )
              .success(function(response) {
                $scope.hideStuff(delId);
              });  

        };
```

Comment: how to use it with `$scope.hideStuff = function (delId) {
                $scope.startFade = true;
                 //here i want to use the index to delete the row
                $scope.hidden = true;
            };`

thanx so much

Comment: @hey you don't need $scope.hidden = true; just use  $("tr-"+delId).hide(); please try this way

Comment: modified to use `{{item.id}}` as the id for the `<tr>`

Comment: @HalaElBarchah please read this answer and see if it's good enough to mark as correct

Comment: it doesnt work, I want to hide the row witch has user id = the `delId` ... so how to pass and use the entered `delId` and row index to delete this row?

Comment: sorry my bad! missing # on $("#tr-"+delId).hide();  try again

Comment: the solution you writed deletes the id column, not the row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91199/discussion-between-alvaro-joao-and-hala-el-barchah).

Comment: can you try again with the html and the js I posted? make sure  `delId` has the correct value